# помогите понять паттерн Фабричный метод

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Не могу понять данный паттерн, а именно, зачем он нужен.
Пример (взят [отсюда](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/factory-method/php/example#example-1) )

В этом примере паттерн Фабричный Метод предоставляет интерфейс для создания коннекторов к социальным сетям, которые могут быть использованы для входа в сеть, создания сообщений и, возможно, выполнения других действий, — и всё это без привязки клиентского кода к определённым классам конкретной социальной сети.

````
<?php

namespace RefactoringGuru\FactoryMethod\RealWorld;

/**
 * Создатель объявляет фабричный метод, который может быть использован вместо
 * прямых вызовов конструктора продуктов, например:
 *
 * - До: $p = new FacebookConnector();
 * - После: $p = $this->getSocialNetwork;
 *
 * Это позволяет подклассам SocialNetworkPoster изменять тип создаваемого
 * продукта.
 */
abstract class SocialNetworkPoster
{
    /**
     * Фактический фабричный метод. Обратите внимание, что он возвращает
     * абстрактный коннектор. Это позволяет подклассам возвращать любые
     * конкретные коннекторы без нарушения контракта суперкласса.
     */
    abstract public function getSocialNetwork(): SocialNetworkConnector;

    /**
     * Когда фабричный метод используется внутри бизнес-логики Создателя,
     * подклассы могут изменять логику косвенно, возвращая из фабричного метода
     * различные типы коннекторов.
     */
    public function post($content): void
    {
        // Вызываем фабричный метод для создания объекта Продукта...
        $network = $this->getSocialNetwork();
        // ...а затем используем его по своему усмотрению.
        $network->logIn();
        $network->createPost($content);
        $network->logout();
    }
}

/**
 * Этот Конкретный Создатель поддерживает Facebook. Помните, что этот класс
 * также наследует метод post от родительского класса. Конкретные Создатели —
 * это классы, которые фактически использует Клиент.
 */
class FacebookPoster extends SocialNetworkPoster
{
    private $login, $password;

    public function __construct(string $login, string $password)
    {
        $this->login = $login;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getSocialNetwork(): SocialNetworkConnector
    {
        return new FacebookConnector($this->login, $this->password);
    }
}

/**
 * Этот Конкретный Создатель поддерживает LinkedIn.
 */
class LinkedInPoster extends SocialNetworkPoster
{
    private $email, $password;

    public function __construct(string $email, string $password)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getSocialNetwork(): SocialNetworkConnector
    {
        return new LinkedInConnector($this->email, $this->password);
    }
}

/**
 * Интерфейс Продукта объявляет поведения различных типов продуктов.
 */
interface SocialNetworkConnector
{
    public function logIn(): void;

    public function logOut(): void;

    public function createPost($content): void;
}

/**
 * Этот Конкретный Продукт реализует API Facebook.
 */
class FacebookConnector implements SocialNetworkConnector
{
    private $login, $password;

    public function __construct(string $login, string $password)
    {
        $this->login = $login;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function logIn(): void
    {
        echo "Send HTTP API request to log in user $this->login with " .
            "password $this->password\n";
    }

    public function logOut(): void
    {
        echo "Send HTTP API request to log out user $this->login\n";
    }

    public function createPost($content): void
    {
        echo "Send HTTP API requests to create a post in Facebook timeline.\n";
    }
}

/**
 * А этот Конкретный Продукт реализует API LinkedIn.
 */
class LinkedInConnector implements SocialNetworkConnector
{
    private $email, $password;

    public function __construct(string $email, string $password)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function logIn(): void
    {
        echo "Send HTTP API request to log in user $this->email with " .
            "password $this->password\n";
    }

    public function logOut(): void
    {
        echo "Send HTTP API request to log out user $this->email\n";
    }

    public function createPost($content): void
    {
        echo "Send HTTP API requests to create a post in LinkedIn timeline.\n";
    }
}

/**
 * Клиентский код может работать с любым подклассом SocialNetworkPoster, так как
 * он не зависит от конкретных классов.
 */
function clientCode(SocialNetworkPoster $creator)
{
    // ...
    $creator->post("Hello world!");
    $creator->post("I had a large hamburger this morning!");
    // ...
}

/**
 * На этапе инициализации приложение может выбрать, с какой социальной сетью оно
 * хочет работать, создать объект соответствующего подкласса и передать его
 * клиентскому коду.
 */
echo "Testing ConcreteCreator1:\n";
clientCode(new FacebookPoster("john_smith", "******"));
echo "\n\n";

echo "Testing ConcreteCreator2:\n";
clientCode(new LinkedInPoster("john_smith@example.com", "******"));```
````

собственно, вопрос.
Зачем нужен фабричный метод, если сам класс SocialNetworkPoster можно спроектировать таким образом, чтобы он внутрь принимал объект нужного класса (FacebookPoster/LinkedInPoster) и работал уже с ним?
Как мне кажется, код в примере нарушает принцип DI

Comment: фу. не делайте так.

Comment: Что тут понимать? Вызываешь функцию - получаешь экземпляр объекта. Просто до тупого.

Comment: Вы спраиваете зачем нужен паттерн Фабрика в вашем коде. А мы откуда знаем? Это ваш код, вам должно быть виднее, зачем он вам нужен.

Comment: Фабрика может быть применима множеством способов. Например QML `Component` - это фабрика. Если говорить о классическом ООП, то Фабрика нужна тогда, когда создание объекта нетривиально, и требует дополнительных действий. В плюсах для этого обычно делают приватный конструктор, и создают объекты через статическую функцию, френд функцию или френд класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, речь идёт о неудачном примере паттерна. Правда, кажется странным создавать столько объектов `*Poster`, в которых отличается только подключение, а всё остальное поведение берётся из класса-родителя.

Мне кажется, что этот код клиентский (не относится к библиотеке, которая инкапсулирует детали работы с социальными сетями).

К библиотечному коду следует отнести классы семейства `*Connector`. Как раз `Connector` можно разбить на две части, одна из которых будет создавать другую. В API социальных сетей есть методы, которые вызываются без аутентификации, не привязаны к пользователю и относятся ко всей социальной сети. Один из этих методов — `login`.

Другие методы могут вызываться только от имени пользователя и требуют специальным образом зашифрованной строки (*токена аутентификации*).

Почему их следует разнести в два класса? Потому что вам может потребоваться сценарий взаимодействия: вы создаёте подключение от имени Ани, затем от имени Бори, Аня пишет Боре, Боря отвечает.

Представим, что у нас есть иерархия `Network`: `FacebookNetwork`, `VKNetwork` и  т.д. Эти классы содержат абстрактные методы, которые инкапсулируют обращения без аутентификации. Фабричным методом будет `login()` или `createUser()`, если угодно. В иерархии `User` (`FacebookUser`, `VKUser`...) спрятаны методы, работающие от имени пользователя и посылающие на сервер токен аутентификации.

```php
class Poster
{
    private $network;

    public function __construct($network) {
        $this->network = $network;
    }

    public function scenario1($login1, $password1, $login2, $password2) {
        $user1 = $this->network->login($login1, $password1);
        $user2 = $this->network->login($login2, $password2);

        $message = $user1->writeTo($user2->id, "Hello!");
        $next_message = $user2->reply($message->id, "Hi! How are you?");
    }
}
```

DI для решения таких задач подходит не очень. Фабричный метод полезен, когда речь идёт не о выделенном классе, а о связанных иерархиях, таких как `Network` и `User`. Объединять эти классы в один неправильно, потому что у них разные сценарии использования. В частности `Network` почти всегда используется в единственном экземпляре в пределах сценария, в то время как экземпляров `User` может быть много.

И расцеплять их с помощью DI неправильно, потому что они тесно связаны. `FacebookNetwork` прекрасно осведомлён о `FacebookUser` и может создать его непосредственно.

Создание посредством DI возможно, но добавляет один уровень косвенности и на ровном месте усложняет код.

Этот пример тоже искусственный, придумывал на ходу. Если бы речь шла не о PHP, а о C#, я бы привёл пример с библиотечными классами `MembershipProvider` и `MembershipUser` Но в PHP аналога мне быстро нагуглить не удалось.

В `MembershipProvider` фабричными методами являются `CreateUser` и `GetUser`. Они переопределяются в дочерних классах `SqlMembershipProvider` или `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` и создают экземпляры класса `MembershipUser`. Однако, второй класс в действительности создаёт `ActiveDirectoryMembershipUser` и храните там дополнительные данные о пользователе Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Если SocialNetworkPoster будет "получать объекты нужного класса" - это означает, что ваш код (клиент) знает о существовании этих объектов и берет на себя их имплементацию. А теперь представьте, что вам не надо реализовывать эти объекты, что уже реализованы имплементации для нескольких целевых систем (в нашем случае - это соц сети), а вам надо только передать в фабрику вариант требуемой имплементации, например, через агрументы и дальше работать, как с абстрактной соц сетью.